# Django model relates to two other models

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to build a dictionary application and having a difficulty with the model.

Now I wrote this

```
class Term(models.Model):
    term_text   = models.CharField("phrase term text", max_length=100)

class Definition(models.Model): 
    term                    = models.ForeignKey(Term)
    definition_text         = models.TextField()


class Country(models.Model):
        #is this correct method?
        #Should i add ForeginKey for both Term and Definition here?
```

The problem is the Country. Both Term and Definition should have a Country field as Term could be available in many countries and a definition could be limited to certain countries with another definition for others.

now how to do this country model?

I've tried to use django-countries as a model field for Term and Definition but its limiting me to use only 1 country per object.

Comment: You can add country's foreign key in Term and Definition then you can have one to many relationship were one Term or Definition can have many Countries

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? adding foreign keys of both term and definition to get one to many? @TanveerAlam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is ManyToMany relationships on both Term and Definition. That way you'll be able to call `my_term.countries` and `my_definition.countries`.

```
class Term(models.Model):
    term_text = models.CharField("phrase term text", max_length=100)
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country)


class Definition(models.Model): 
    term = models.ForeignKey(Term)
    definition_text = models.TextField()
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country)


class Country(models.Model):
    # define Country model

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "countries"
```